# Moved CrashPlan backup location but files in old location persist

Tags: backup, crashplan

When I installed CrashPlan on my Windows 8 computer its default was to backup up to the "Program Data" directory of the OS partition (`C:`). I did not notice this and ran this way for a week or so. When I noticed that my `C:` drive was running out of space, I decided to backup to an external hard drive (`V:`).

So, I changed the changed the settings in CrashPlan so that by default it would backup to `V:`. Since I had already backed up around 60 GB to the `C:` drive, I changed the location of the backup for that existing backup and CrashPlan helpfully copied the existing files to the `V:` drive.

I would have thought that after copying the files from `C:` to `V:`, CrashPlan would have deleted the files on `C:`, but it did not: they remain in `C:\Program Data`. Can I safely delete those files? Is there a reason that CrashPlan did not remove the original files?